# Antonym of "capital"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

What is the antonym of "capital" (in the sense of city of governmental seat)? A related question: is there a term for referring to the whole set of cities that are not the capital within a country (or state, province)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provincial. This is the term sometimes used in the UK.

Comment: Ok, but if I want to say, for example, that I live in some English city, but not London. How am I to say that? "I live in the _countryside_"? Is there a better term than that?

Comment: What was unclear about "provincial"? You live in a provincial city.

Comment: +1 _NOAD_: **[provincial](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/provincial?region=us)**

Comment: @Otavio: If you said you live in the *countryside*, that would imply that you did not live in a town or city at all. As @Marcin says, *provincial city* would work.

Answer (score 2):

The first word that comes to my mind is **non-capital**.

For example,

> What are the largest non-capital cities in the
>   world?

**Minor**, **secondary** or **inferior** also come to mind.